# Dynamically display contents of sqlite db in a HTML page based on column pull downs

Tags: php, python, html, sqlite

I have a table in a sqlite db, and I would like to display it on a webpage.
The column titles are the same as in the db. I also need a pull down listing all the unique values in each column so that I can select to filter which rows to display.

By example, sqlite db:

```
1 2 3
a l z
b k w
b m x
a m w
d m y
c l w
```

Displayed on a webpage like:

```
1 2 3
v v v
a l z
b k w
b m x
a m w
d m y
c l w
```

Where each 'v' represents the pulldown, so:
col 1 v = all,a,b,d,c; col 2 v = all,l,k,m; col 3 v = all,z,w,x,y
i.e. take all the entries in a column, uniquify, and use that to populate the pulldown. Order doesn't matter.

Then, if the user selects, say 'b' in col 1 pull down, the webpage would display:

```
1 2 3
v v v
b k w
b m x
```

If the user then selects 'x' in col 3 pull down, the webpage would display:

```
1 2 3
v v v
b m x
```

I've been searching around for ways to go about implementing this, but I'm struggling to work out what would be the most suitable, and where to start.

I know HTML, some php, python, perl, basic js, and this is my first attempt with sqlite (or any db).

I'm looking for suggestions as to what would be a recommended way to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: do u need help with the sql query or idea for implementation?

Comment: Ideas for implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can see this example that i made:

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/3e8souur/28/)

ofcourse you can change the data here:

```
> var data = '{ "a": [ [ "a", "b", "c", "a"], ["a", "e", "f", "f"],
> ["g", "h", "h", "i"]]}';
```

Good Luck!